# Hide all but 1 dif on document ready and unhide divs after "change"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a business options form (rough description I know, but here goes). I want the first `select` that pops up to be to choose an Entity Type (IE: Corporation, LLC, LLP, etc). Once one of these is chosen, I want to `.show()` the next `form`. Here is what I've tried so far:

HTML FILE

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hide.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
        function getEntityType(sel) {
            var openingEntityType = sel.value;
            $("#basicOpeningEntityInformation").show();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="oet" onchange="getEntityType(this)">
        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
        <option value="inc">Corporation</option>
        <option value="llc">Limited Liability Company</option>
        <option value="llp">Limited Liability Partnership</option>
        <option value="lp">Limited Partnership</option>
        <option value="gp">General Partnership</option>
        <option value="jv">Joint Venture</option>
        <option value="dba">Sole Proprietorship</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <form id="basicOpeningEntityInformation">
        Entity Name:
        <input type="text" id="openingEntityName">
        <br/>
    </form>
</body>
```

CSS FILE:

```
#basicOpeningEntityInformation {
    display: none;
}
```

When the page loads, `#basicOpeningEntityInformation` is hidden. I want it to be unhide when a `select` from above is chosen. I tested my console and the `select` is passing it's `value` to `var openingEntityType` as it should; however, it is not making the other form visible. I tired with both `.basicOpeningEntityInformation` and `#basicOpeningEntityInformation` and neither seem to work (both in the `CSS` and the `Script`.

Thank you!

Comment: Working fine **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ju84b0rb/)**

Comment: Can we see some javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the selected value is one of the required values:

```
$('#oet').on('change', function() {
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    if (selectedItem == 'inc' || selectedItem == 'llc' || selectedItem == 'llp') {
        $('#basicOpeningEntityInformation').show();
    } else {
        $('#basicOpeningEntityInformation').hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/L4b0wpts/1/

Comment: @jpgerb Can you create jsfiddle

Comment: your fiddle works - Basically I just needed to specify if the `value` == x,y,z instead of just leaving it blank. Cool! Thanks! I'll accept when the system lets me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this..it will  work

```js
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hide.css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"> </script>
 <script>
        function getEntityType(sel) {
            var openingEntityType = sel.value;
            jQuery("#basicOpeningEntityInformation").show();
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

you are using $(".basicOpeningEntityInformation").show();

so change the

> id="basicOpeningEntityInformation"  to  class="basicOpeningEntityInformation"

OR

> $(".basicOpeningEntityInformation").show(); to $("#basicOpeningEntityInformation").show();

Comment: I think the js file u linked is not having the events u firing.   try adding this 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"> </script>
 
  <script>
        function getEntityType(sel) {
            var openingEntityType = sel.value;
            jQuery("#basicOpeningEntityInformation").show();
        }
    </script>